# how I can add contactus inside the body of mailto, when click in the button open email by mailto then in the body add text and add contactus

Tags: mailto

I have a button when click it open email with text in the body and also in the body I have contact us when click it open the email of the coach

```
input type="button"; value="Click me"; onclick="window.location.herf='mailto:me@any.com?subject=Request%20invite&body=Hallo%20you' + ' http://www.google.com' + 'HIIIIII' + 'window.open('mailto:address@dmail.com')'";>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the `contactus` text and a link to open an email to a coach in the body of a mailto link, you can use the following code:

```
input type="button"; 
value="Click me"; 
onclick="window.location.herf='mailto:me@any.com?subject=Request%20invite&body=Hallo%20you%0D%0A%0D%0AContactus:%20http://www.google.com%0D%0A%0D%0AHIIIIII%0D%0A%0D%0AFor%20questions%20or%20concerns,%20please%20contact%20our%20coach%20at:%20mailto:address@dmail.com'";>
```

In the code above, I added the contactus text and a link to http://www.google.com after the Hallo you text in the body of the email. I also added a line break (%0D%0A) after each line of text to make the email more readable.

Additionally, I added a line of text at the end of the email body that says "For questions or concerns, please contact our coach at: mailto:address@dmail.com". This will create a clickable link in the email that will open a new email to the coach when clicked.

Comment: it is still not working